# Create a database in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, sql, database, intellij-idea

I have to create a database having the name Cars using any RDBMS (Oracle, Postgres, MySql, Java DB, etc.).
Then I have to create a user with the name "dbus" and the password "uspass"; and 2 tables.

Can any of you explain to me how I can create a database in intellij? I can't find any options.

I read somewhere that I have to download a database browser, I downloaded it and I don't think I can create a new database. As far as I understand, this "db browser" only establishes a connection to an existing database.

I just want to create a database where I can create some tables. Then with the connection I hope I can handle it.

Comment: Google is your friend, friend; https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/database-tool-window.html

Comment: I don'h have this option. My question is : Can I create a database in intellij or just establish a connection with an existing one, created with another platform (oracle sql developer, mysql etc.)? What exactly does / means db browser?

Comment: Your question was how you can create, not can you create. You simply have to read the link I posted to learn more about the topic. You need to research. This isn't a programming related problem, letaone java.

Comment: @Jason Correction: Questions about how to [use programming tools *is* on-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288832/642706) here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: The Jetbrains link is possibly not relevant since it applies only to IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate.

Answer (score 3):

For most data sources you have to provide the URL of the existing database where you can create tables, etc.

The database needs to already exist and you should use the administrative tools for the corresponding RDBMS to create a database and a user first. Only after that you can connect and work with this database in the IDE.

As far as I know, creating the database directly from IntelliJ IDEA is possible only for the Embedded Apache Derby data source:

[image: Create database]

P.S. Database plug-in is available only in [*IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate*](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) edition. And same functionality built into their separate product, [*DataGrip*](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/).

Comment: so i guess this confirms it is not possible, thanks